# Sending post request to restful with retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I'm on a project which uses restful API.
I tried to use retrofit 2.0 for sending a post request to the service, but I only get error 500.

I don't know what is my error.

Here is my Main activity:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().
            baseUrl(url).
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
            build();

    final RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
            loginRequest.setAction("loginvendor");
            loginRequest.setAppkey(PharmaApp.APPKEY);
            loginRequest.setFilters("title,entity_id,email");
            loginRequest.setUsername("pvakriraevil93@gmail.com");
            loginRequest.setPassword("12345612");
            final Call<UserSystem> usercall =  restInterface.getUser("loginvendor",PharmaApp.APPKEY,"pvakriraevil93@gmail.com","12345612","title,entity_id,email");
            Log.e("Data request",usercall+"");
            usercall.enqueue(new Callback<UserSystem>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UserSystem> call, Response<UserSystem> response) {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, ""+statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UserSystem> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("onFailure", ""+ t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "onFailure__"+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is my Interface:

```
public interface RestInterface {

@POST("rest/mobileapi")
Call<UserSystem> getUser(@Field("action") String action,
                         @Field("appkey") String appkey,
                         @Field("username") String username,
                         @Field("password") String password,
                         @Field("filters") String filters);
}
```

This is my UserSystem file:

```
public class UserSystem {

@SerializedName("entity_id")
@Expose
private int entity_id;

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String name;



public UserSystem(){

}

public int getId() {
    return entity_id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.entity_id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

and my json file in webservice

[image]

Comment: 500 is internal server error so that mistake in webservice try to get response using postman

Comment: i used postman for test but no problem, is my code no mistakes?

Comment: Have you tried adding '@FormUrlEncoded' annotation above '@POST("rest/mobileapi")'